# Having to switch between default gateways to regain internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

[image]**Quick topology:**
I have a fairly busy but simple network. I have 4 locations, each with their own gateway to the WAN, and all connected via wireless Ubiquiti bridges that block DHCP. This way it can basically be one big network with 4 internet connections. Most everything besides cellphones are set up statically.
All windows PC's. Also all Ubiquiti edge routers, bridges, and ubiquiti unifi AP's for wireless clients

**The Problem:**
Recently I had a bridge that was connecting location 1 to location 2 that seemed to be failing, So I isolated location 2 and reconnected it to my network through location 3

Didn't think much of it since from the surface all seemed well, but the next day when people came to work there were several people who couldn't connect to the web.

**How I seemed to fix this:**
I found by simply changing their default gateway to a different location and then back to the same brought them back online.

**Question:**
I have had something similar happen with some of my Asrock PC's when I switched their LAN cable to a different port, but I assumed it was something funny with the LAN card. **BUT now with this wider scale event, I'm curious if someone has an explanation of what is happening here?**

I obviously know enough to be dangerous =) but I am not really familiar with the deeper meaning on some of these issues.

Comment: What are the host OS''s? What is the bridge that's failing? Is it a physical bridge, or logical? If it's physical, update your question with model numbers etc, if it's logical you should add your config steps to the question. From what I have seen, the more information you give the community in your question, the less generic your answers will be! Best Regards,

Comment: I guess I am kind of wondering if there's a "generic" reasoning as to why switching up network routes would cause PC's to be unable to find the WAN. If not then yes it would evoke a lot more detail to figure out.. I was trying to keep the question simpler although I'm sure I failed at that =)

Comment: There are some aspects of the topology that are not clear. You say you are bridging between sites and that you filter DHCP, so all PCs get DG from the local bridge but sit on the same subnet ? I suspect that somehow a cache (may be ARP) is the culprit here.

Comment: @CarlosMendioroz I have few DHCP devices and the only ones I've had this issue with are Static PC's. But yes, any DHCP devices get there DG from their local router. Each location has one router that connects to the web. So if you pretend the wireless bridges are Just long DHCP blocking Ethernet cables, Then My network is basically one big network with 4 routers that connect their static block to the internet. (I do occationally switch DG's for some PC's to help with bottlenecks on our slow internet) If you have any suspected theories I'd appreciate them.

Comment: So you have a square, and 2 links at each location forming a ring, at layer 2. Then spanning tree should be working somehow, or this would not work. (I'd have to check Ubiquiti to find how). Please confirm each Ubiquiti handles 2 bridges, an Internet access and a local zone. And what (at a more detailed level) do you mean by "reconnected through location 2". A sample drawing of the topology would help a lot :)

Comment: @CarlosMendioroz Location 2 has line of site to both location 1 and location 3 So I just simply shutdown the wireless bridge that was having a weak signal issue, and setup a different bridge to bring location 3 back into the network via location 2 is all. in essence, I guess I am kind of wondering if there's a simple reason as to why switching up network routes would cause PC's to be unable to find the WAN. You stated something about a cache. Is there actually somewhere that holds a cache of a PC's route to the web that can cause an issue?

Comment: I still don't get the actual topology, but every bridge has a "route" for where each MAC is, i.e., to which interface traffic destined to the MAC has to go. When you change the topology, that's a "cache" or memory that may cause truble. Another is the MAC of the router that holds the DG. Even if it is the same router, each interface does have a MAC so if you reach your DG via one bridge and then it changes to be reachable through another, the MAC would be invalid and... it would not work any longer. That would be ARP in the PC.

Comment: After a little research it would make sense to me that this issue could be ARP related. I have also switched routers and other equipment a few times. Would it make sense after making network routing changes to maybe clear the ARP cache on devices or maybe upon a restart, devices should relearn there connections

Comment: ARP entries expire by themselves, and usually that works well. If you do make a diagram of the topology, I could be able to make up a probable cause :)

Comment: @CarlosMendioroz I sort of put together a topology besides every location has several switches and such so they are quite a bit bigger than just a couple PC's =).. I also have a Unifi controller at one location that runs the wifi AP's for all locations. (Ubiquiti's way of doing it) and one location has a Disney Circle that is hooked to only it's DG. I sometimes wonder if that thing can't cause network issues.

Comment: Ok, you don't have a cycle in L2, so you may be not running STP. If your DG on the PCs that lost connection was local, I don't find a possible explanation. If your DG was not local, then the change in topology could have changed the MAC associated to it: If you had S1 <-> S2 <-> S3 <-> S4 and a site4 PC was using a site3 DG, then the DG MAC would be the one of the port at site 3 to the bridge to site 4. Now, if you reconnect site 4 via site 2, the DG MAC would change to the MAC of the port at site 3 to the bridge to site 2! PC traffic to DG would go blackhole.